# How to export Azure Dashboards to Excel

Tags: excel, azure, azure-devops, dashboard

TIA:

Trying to find a way to export/embed/link the azure DevOps Dashboards to excel.

I am pretty new to Azure DevOps, would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for checking in @LeoLiu-MSFT, I do need more assistance here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps Dashboards does not support integration with Excel. The full information about Dashboards you can find here: [About dashboards, charts, reports, & widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops). There was the similar question here: [Export Dashboard](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/836100/export-dashboard-1.html).

If you want to export dashboards, you have to build your own one with PowerBI: [About Power BI integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops)